# Shibboleth with Node.js Rest API and Angular 2 Application

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, single-sign-on, shibboleth

a university wants an application with Shibboleth authentication. They provide their own IDP.
I want to make a Node.Js backend and Angular frontend. They both should communicate with REST. Is it still possible to integrate Shibboleth Service Provider to Node.Js backend and authenticate over Angular frontend?

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is possible. NodeJS has passport, which is an authentication provider that can be easily extended for various cases, including Shibboleth.

A plugin of passport, named passport-saml offer the integration of Shibboleth.

Passport : http://passportjs.org/

Passport-saml: https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-saml

Comment: Do you know how to register my site as as service provider for shibboleth? I'm confused as to the steps I need to take to integrate shibboleth login into my website.

Comment: @EthanSK I would love to be able to answer you, but at the time I wrote this answer, I pretty much just googled it. I would invite you to do the same.

Comment: I literally spent many hours trying to find the answer. There is no documentation anywhere, I would appreciate it if you enlightened me. All I want to do is register my webapp as a service provider so that users can press a login button and login with their uni credentials, and the identity can be sent back to my service. There doesn't seem to be anything on this anywhere, I spent so many hours.